Defining authorization route in Openapi/Swagger for a passport.js Oauth route that returns a cookie
I have an express application that uses passport.js to authenticate. The authentication endpoints use Oauth 2.0, and after all the redirects etc, set a connect.sid cookie which is sent on subsequent requests to establish whether a user has been authenticated. The app is working great and the protected endpoints all work after authentication. But I can't figure out how to document this endpoint in the Swagger UI so that a user can obtain the cookie. Is this even possible?
Currently I have my Openapi yaml set to accept a cookie for authorization which does seem to work.
components:
  # 1) Define the cookie name
  securitySchemes:
    cookieAuth:        
      type: apiKey
      in: cookie
      name: connect.sid  # cookie name

# 2) Apply cookie auth globally to all operations
security:
  - cookieAuth: []

But I would like to document the login endpoint and allow users to be able to click "try it out" in the ui and then be able to obtain their cookie. Is this even possible? Or will the "try it out" button just not work for this specific endpoint?
Thanks!
